# How do I redirect the user to another page in Play Framework?

Tags: redirect, http-headers, playframework

I need to direct the user to another URL after the server has received some form data. How can I redirect the user in Play Framework?

I have tried with:

```
   val url = "http://127.0.0.1:9000/user/" + user.id + "/" + user.name
   response.setHeader("Location", url)
```

But the user is not redirected. With PHP I can do this using:

```
header('Location: http://127.0.0.1:9000/user/'.user->id.'/'.user->name);
```

I have tried to use `Action(MyController.myMethod)` but then is not the "preferred" URL used. How do I set a redirect header using Play Framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply use?

```
redirect("http://www.zenexity.fr");
```

Comment: I use the Scala module. It looks like `redirect` isn't available from Scala: `not found: value redirect` or what do I need to import?

Comment: http://scala.playframework.org/documentation/scala-0.9/controllers#Redirect isn't it this one?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the reverse router, something similar to this should work:

```
Redirect(mypackage.myitems.routes.MyController.myItem(myItemId))
```

The parameter is optional.